# How can I show all contacts by default?

Tags: contact, tab

When I click on the contacts tab I want by default to show all contacts? How Do I Do this?

Answer (score 5):

This is a common question, but you're probably missing the point of this tab if you think that all it is for is showing a list of contacts. This is called the contacts home tab, and its purpose is to give you access to your recent contacts and some utilities, such as the import contacts wizard, mass deletion wizard, reports, and more (your features will vary depending on your permissions and organization edition/features).

However, if you're still intent on giving up all this extra functionality for the sake of going directly into a view of all contacts (from the contacts home tab, all contacts is just a click away by clicking on "Go!"), you can override the default page. Just remember, you won't be able to easily access the page *at all* if you choose to do this.

First, go to *Setup > Develop > Pages*, and click on "New." Give it a name, and enter the following code:

```
<apex:page action="/{!$ObjectType.Contact.keyPrefix}" standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="contacts">
</apex:page>
```

Next, go to *Setup > Customize > Contacts > Buttons, Links, and Actions*, click "Edit" next to *Contacts Tab*, and choose your new page.

Now, when you click on the Contacts tab, it will take you to your last list view. Simply choose the "All Contacts" view, and salesforce.com will remember this selection for you. However, you won't be able to click on any standard element to return back to the "home" tab, so you'll lose immediate access to the *Tools* and *Reports* quick links.

Comment: Firstly, I like your answer. Secondly, I think I read the question wrong. My impression was that on the Contacts Home Tab, is it possible to show the All Contacts list view instead of the Recently Viewed List View. I have wondered if setting a "default" list view is possible.

Comment: You get three views on the home tab: Recently Created, Recently Modified, and Recently Viewed. It's like the main home tab; it's just an overview, rather than a full list view.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a bit of a hack and List Views.

1. Open the List View to show all Contacts.
2. Get the URL for that view. It'll be something like https://[instance].salesforce.com/003?fcf=[ListViewId]
3. Create a custom tab, All Contacts. Set the URL for this tab to be the URL from step 2.
4. If you want to replace the normal Contacts tab, set its visibility to "Default Off" for your users. Do not set it to Hidden or you'll disable searching for that object for those users.

Comment: Custom tabs are limited as opposed to Visualforce pages (unless they're on Unlimited Edition). This being said, this solution is equally valid to my proposal. And, it's usually a bad idea to link to a specific list view in case someone later deletes it.

Comment: Good point on this breaking if the list view is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's having this issue 7 years later :)
Next to the name of the list view, there's a pin icon. Click it to pin the list view as your default.