# How do i show all campaign members by default when I click on the campaigns tab?

Tags: campaign, tab

How do I show all campaign members by default when I click on the campaigns tab, while sowing all the other campaign fields?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I show all contacts by default?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/how-can-i-show-all-contacts-by-default)

Comment: I don't think so; the question appears to be about showing actual campaign members (people) on the Campaigns tab / list view, which can't be done with the standard Campaigns tab.